# Convergence almost surely via Simple linear regression

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ anf $Y$ be two random variables with finite second moments ($EX^2 \leftarrow\infty$ , $EY^2 \leftarrow\infty$) and are related by $Y=aX+b+\epsilon$ when $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon$ is a random variable (error). Assume that $a$, $b$ are unknown as well as the distribution of $X$ and $Y$

i) Show that

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2 \text{ and }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$$

converge almost surely to $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$, respectively , as $n \rightarrow\infty$, where
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\ldots\text{ and } \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=i}^nY_i ,\ldots$$

---

From $a_n= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i-(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\dfrac{(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^2}{n}}$

You can admit that $a_n$ converges almost surely to $a$ , as $n$ $\rightarrow\infty$ , for now.

Let   $b_n = \bar{Y}-a_n\bar{X}$
and  $\hat{Y_i}= a_n X_i +b_n$

ii) Verity that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{Y_i}-\bar{Y})^2 = a^2_n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$$

and Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{Y_i}-\bar{Y})^2$ converges almost surely to $a^2 Var(X)$

---

iii) Show that

$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{Y_i}-\bar{Y})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}$ converges almost surely to $\dfrac{a^2 Var(X)}{Var(Y)}$

---

iv) Show that $a_n= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i-(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\dfrac{(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^2}{n}}$  converges almost surely to $a$ , as $n \rightarrow\infty$

and $b_n =\bar{Y} -a_n \bar{X}$ converges almost surely to $b$ , as $n \rightarrow\infty$

---

***My Solution***

i) Suppose

$$S_n= \frac{{1}}{{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X_n})^2$$

$$=\frac{{1}}{{n}}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2+2(X_i-u)(u-\bar{X_n})+(u-\bar{X_n})^2)]$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)(u-\bar{X_n})+(u-\bar{X_n})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2+2(u-\bar{X_n})\frac{{1}}{{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)+(u-\bar{X_n})^2$$

$$=\frac{{1}}{{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2+2(u-\bar{X_n})\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i)-u+(u-\bar{X_n})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2+2(u-\bar{X_n})(\bar{X_n}-u)+(u-\bar{X_n})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-u)^2-(\bar{X_n}-u)^2$$

By the Strong of Large Number, So that

$$\bar{X} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i) \rightarrow u\text{ almost surely}$$

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X_n})^2 \rightarrow u E((X_i-\bar{X_n})^2) = Var(X) \text{ almost surely}$$

Hence $S_n \rightarrow Var(X)$ almost surely

True or False ??? (if True Step solution of almost surely $Var(Y)$ similar Solution of almost surely $Var(X)$  ???)

---

Solution For ii) iii) and iv) I don't know how to deal with.  thanks for any help.??  Thanks ;)

Comment: Some of your ways of using TeX look like the work of a lunatic.  Writing \frac{{1}}{{n}} where \frac{1}{n} or even \frac1n will suffice, or writing $a$-$b$ where $a-b$ is (for excellent and obvious reasons) standard, etc.

Comment: Your answer to (i) looks alright to me.  The next part will probably be more involved.